# Liaison in french dialects

Tags: prononciation, liaisons, dialectes

Are there conservative dialects of french in which the phenomenon of liaison is not present,so that consonants at the end of words are always fully pronounced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have a liaison, on the contrary you do not pronounce the consonant at the end ;

> liaison : un gran*t* arbre (un grand arbre)
>
> no liaison : un gran arbre (un grand arbre)

There aren't, properly speaking, dialects of French, merely regional particularities which are never too far removed from main stream French. What you find, though, is a number of completely different "languages" ; they are limited to regions too, are not always full fledged languages (no written form) ; some of them are call "patois" in French ("patois du Midi" for instance) ; others are ancient languages such as Provençal (written form) ; it is not known for some of them, such as Corsican, whether they should be called "patois" or "langue" (not all people agree on that point).
Therefore there does not exist a dialect with such caracteristics as you mention ; however, French people in the lower classes and those with less education use less  liaisons than the rest of the population.

Moreover, the art of liaisons **is** a conservative caracteristic of the language.

Comment: Linguists tend to avoid using *patois* which has often a derogatory meaning. Anyway, what you call *patois du midi* are dialects of a pretty ancient written language called *langue d'oc* and used by the *troubadours* in the middle ages while *provençal* is also a dialect of the former which can be written either the classical *langue d'oc* (*occitan*) way or with a modern orthography (*graphie mistralienne*). Corsican is never called a patois, it is a language considered to be part of the Toscan family.

Comment: @jlliagre  It's not what I call it but what the people who are using it, themselves use to call it fifty years ago and there was nothing derogatory about that and no other term ; if it wasn't French, it could only be patois ; don't  they know better than anyone what that has been called for ages  ? Moreover this term is used ([commonly)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patois). I hold from Corsicans themselves that they tend not to consider Corsican as a true language as there no established orthography for the words and even several forms for a  word.

Comment: @jlliagre L'article suivant confirme qu'en Provence, il y a du monde qui considère que le provençal est une [langue](http://salonpatrimoineetchemins.fr/upload/visite_maillane.pdf). On y parle de la « langue provençale ».

Comment: Je n'ai pas écrit que le provençal n'était pas une langue, c'est bien sûr une langue, comme le corse, le gascon, le languedocien, l'auvergnat, le catalan, le basque, le breton, le wallon, le picard, etc. Les langues ne sont définies que par le fait qu'elles sont ou qu'elles ont été parlées. Qu'il existe des variations temporelles, régionales, locales, familiales, individuelles est un fait connu. Une langue n'a pas besoin d'être standardisée ou écrite pour être une *vraie langue*.

Comment: Si des corses t'ont dit que le corse n'est pas une vraie langue, c'est qu'on leur a mis ça dans la tête à l'école puisque la république a longtemps méprisé et tenté d'éradiquer les langues régionales, et continue d'ailleurs de refuser de ratifier la charte européenne des langues régionales ou minoritaires.

Comment: @jlliagre Selon cette terminologie que sont les patois si ce ne sont pas des langues et pourquoi ne sont-ils pas des langues ?

Comment: *Patois* ne fait pas partie de la terminologie des linguistes.Ils ne connaissent que des langues et des dialectes. La frontière entre langues est parfois floue, ainsi que la frontière entre les langues, leurs dialectes et les dialectes entre eux. "Une langue est un dialecte avec une armée et une marine" a dit le linguiste Max Weinreich. *Patois* est un mot qui est parfois encore employé par des gens qui disent qu'ils parlent patois, sans que ce soit alors péjoratif. Autrement, *patois* a souvent un côté méprisant.